# How do I integrate old Fortran/VS program into the new products?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, linker-errors, intel-fortran

I am trying to help with a project from work that was written with Fortran/C++. It is compiled on the native machine using ComposerXE-2011 and Visual Studio 11.0. I have installed on my home computer where I am trying to work on this Visual Studio 2022 and Fortran Compiler 2023.2.1.7. The way the program works is there is a GUI for the code and then they created a command line script that runs through all the files and recompiles the program with the changes made by the proprietary GUI. I have tried changing the command line environment references in their provided setenv.cmd file and get one of three errors depending on which vars.bat file I call.

Error One: LNK1104: Cannot open file ifconsol.lib
Error Two: LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol _printf (also ___iob_func)
Error Three: Wrong architecture, target is x86

I don't have a lot of experience coding in these languages, I just know how to get what I want out of the GUI code builder and then run the script to recompile. I do that at the office all the time, I would like to be able to work on some of it from home. Thank You for your assists!

Here is a the current setenv.cmd somewhat scrubbed to protect the project and proprietary programs

All of the (Drive and whatevers) are the path names and drive letter without the ().

```
@set S3BASE=(Drive and Root)
@set S3BIN=%S3BASE%\bin\ia32
@set S3_BIN=%S3BASE%\bin
@set S3_HOME=(Drive and Root)
@set S3_ENV=(Drive and Root)\s3env
@set S3_ODS=(Drive and root)\ods
@set MBINS=(Drive\Folder\Program)\mbin;(Drive\Folder\Program)\mbin\ia32;
@set path=%path%;(Drive and Root);%S3BIN%;%S3_BIN%;%MBINS%;(Drive\Folder\Program)\jre\bin;B:\rktools\bin;B:\Alias
@set include=%include%;%S3BASE%\include;
@set include=%include%;(Drive And Dependency)\API\Windows\USBDisplayApi\Header;(Drive and Dependency)\API\Windows\hidapi
@set path=%path%;(Drive and Dependency)\API\Windows\USBDisplayApi\Release
@if NOT %COMPUTERNAME%==(Project Name) (
@REM CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\ComposerXE-2011\bin\ifortvars.bat" ia32
@REM CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
@CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext\vcvars.bat" x86
@CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat" ia32
)
```

Comment: Your title is not really describing yoir actual problem. I suggest to make it much more specific.

Comment: I created a title based on my understanding of what i am trying to do. If you have a suggestion of something better you are welcome to suggest it.

Comment: Please confirm: What is your operating system version? What kind of CPU architecture do you have?

Comment: Also, I do not really understand what is really happenning. Is the GUI what you are compiling? Or is it something external already compiled and executable? Does the GUI modify the code to be compiled?

Comment: The PC I have at home is running Windows 11, the PC on the project is Windows 10. Updating the PC involved in the project is not an option. It is air gapped which makes updating difficult and there is no money for more licenses. There are also multiple units.  I'll have to check the CPU on the project but I have an i7. The project pc is operating in a 32-bit environment, that's all I know at the moment.

Comment: The GUI modifies the code. Then I have to run a batch file that runs the compiler in the command line environment. The batch file runs a proprietary program that compiles the program to run on the project. I don't know a lot about that program other than it throws those errors.

Comment: I first wrote that you should just open a ticket at your work but then I realized it is your home PC where you have a problem. With this kind of a messy complex problem of proprietary software doing stuff in intermediate steps you will really be on your own. I doubt anyone will be able to help you much here.

Comment: I am really hoping you are wrong, but I also think you are probably right. I saw on a different question there was a way to fix the the printf unresolved error by linking to a library legacy_stdio_definitions.lib but I don’t know if I can do that from the command line or in the batch file or if it has to be in the program itself.